# SqlAlchemy access column from a relationship-table

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have a model with a many-to-many relationship und want to save specific data to the relationship, how can I access the column in the relationship table?

F. e.

```
borrow = db.Table('borrow',
                    db.Column('book_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('book.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
                    db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True),
                    db.Column('deadline', db.Date, nullable=False))

class Book(Base):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

class Person(Base):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
     borrow = db.relationship('Book', secondary=borrow, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('person', lazy=true))


book = Book(name="MyBook")
person = Person(name="John")
person.borrow.append(book)
```

But how can I save or access the deadline? The column is in my db, but I can't use it in the code

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor Borrow as a class, like you have already done with Book and Person, and then you can set the deadline when you instantiate an instance of Borrow.

See an example from the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/_modules/examples/association/basic_association.html).